# midnight-mode add-to-list Format specifier doesn't match argument type

Tags: list

I've been trying to get midnight-mode to add to the following list. I have a feeling it has to do with an elisp error in my config I'm not seeing. It works fine with setq, but with add-to-list I get a type error:

clean-buffer-list: Format specifier doesn’t match argument type

```
(add-to-list 'clean-buffer-list-kill-regexps
             '("^magit"
               "\.log$"))
```

I tried many variants of this with single quotes around the inside like in the docs \'^magit\'" I no longer get the error, but I also don't get a match. If I use just one item not in a list, it also works, but I want to add several things here.

## My Final Solution

```
(setq clean-buffer-list-kill-regexps (nconc clean-buffer-list-kill-regexps
       '(
         "\\`magit"
         "\\.log\\'"
         )))
```

Corrected the wiki error, for further information see:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CleanBufferList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add them one by one, otherwise you wont't be adding N regexps to the list but you'll be adding 1 (sub)list element to the list:

```
(add-to-list 'clean-buffer-list-kill-regexps "\\`magit")
(add-to-list 'clean-buffer-list-kill-regexps "\\.log\\'")
```

I fixed some errors and misfeatures of your regexps along the way.  If you don't like the duplication you can do:

```
(dolist (re '("\\`magit" "\\.log\\'"))
  (add-to-list 'clean-buffer-list-kill-regexps re))
```

Comment: I was basing my attempts on the example:

    (add-to-list 'clean-buffer-list-kill-regexps
                 '("\\`\\*Customize .*\\*\\'"
                   "\\`\\*\\(Wo\\)?Man .*\\*\\'"))

at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CleanBufferList

I see on http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_regex_begin_end_line_string.html, the different ticks are beginning of string vs line (though they both work here it seems.)

Comment: Yeah, I went through a similar thing a few weeks ago. I believe the examples on the emacswiki page are just wrong, with regard to their usage of `add-to-list` -- although it is possible that it used to act differently in older Emacsen, midnight-mode has been around for a while.

Comment: Seems there is a comment on the wiki from 2015 on how the examples don't work...

Comment: Indeed, the examples are just wrong.  It would be appreciated if you could correct them.